# MySQL: Union, Count, and Group By

Tags: sql, mysql, count, group-by, union

```
(
SELECT root_tags.tag_id, root_tags.tag_name, COUNT( root_tagged.pg_id )
FROM root_tags

LEFT JOIN root_tagged ON ( root_tagged.tag_id = root_tags.tag_id )
LEFT JOIN root_pages ON ( root_pages.pg_id =  root_tagged.pg_id )
LEFT JOIN root_granted ON ( root_granted.pg_id =  root_tagged.pg_id )

WHERE root_pages.parent_id = '5'
AND root_granted.mem_id = '3'

GROUP BY root_tags.tag_id
ORDER BY 3 DESC
)

UNION
(
SELECT root_tags.tag_id, root_tags.tag_name, COUNT( root_tagged.pg_id )
FROM root_tags

LEFT JOIN root_tagged ON ( root_tagged.tag_id = root_tags.tag_id )
LEFT JOIN root_pages ON ( root_pages.pg_id =  root_tagged.pg_id )

WHERE root_pages.parent_id = '5'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM root_granted
    WHERE root_granted.pg_id =  root_pages.pg_id )

GROUP BY root_tags.tag_id
ORDER BY 3 DESC
)
```

The query above returns a result like this below,

```
tag_id  tag_name                COUNT(root_tags.tag_id)
16      expert-category-c       2
14      expert-category-a       1
15      expert-category-b       1
16      expert-category-c       1
```

As you can see the `tag_id 16` is repeated, how can I rewrite the query so that the `tag_id 16` has the count number of `3`, I mean I want the query supposed to return a result like this,

```
tag_id  tag_name                COUNT(root_tags.tag_id)
16      expert-category-c       3
14      expert-category-a       1
15      expert-category-b       1
```

I tried with this query but it returns error...

```
(
SELECT root_tags.tag_id, root_tags.tag_name, COUNT( root_tagged.pg_id )
FROM root_tags

LEFT JOIN root_tagged ON ( root_tagged.tag_id = root_tags.tag_id )
LEFT JOIN root_pages ON ( root_pages.pg_id =  root_tagged.pg_id )
LEFT JOIN root_granted ON ( root_granted.pg_id =  root_tagged.pg_id )

WHERE root_pages.parent_id = '5'
AND root_granted.mem_id = '3'

)

UNION
(
SELECT root_tags.tag_id, root_tags.tag_name, COUNT( root_tagged.pg_id )
FROM root_tags

LEFT JOIN root_tagged ON ( root_tagged.tag_id = root_tags.tag_id )
LEFT JOIN root_pages ON ( root_pages.pg_id =  root_tagged.pg_id )

WHERE root_pages.parent_id = '5'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM root_granted
    WHERE root_granted.pg_id =  root_pages.pg_id )
)

GROUP BY root_tags.tag_id
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Could you please let me know how to make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The better query is given further below, upon analyzing your actual query.

You can merge the two queries using UNION ALL instead of UNION (to retain duplicates), then run a GROUP BY across the entire set.

```
SELECT tag_id, tag_name, SUM(CountTags) as CountTags
FROM
(
SELECT root_tags.tag_id, root_tags.tag_name, COUNT( root_tagged.pg_id ) CountTags
FROM root_tags

LEFT JOIN root_tagged ON ( root_tagged.tag_id = root_tags.tag_id )
LEFT JOIN root_pages ON ( root_pages.pg_id =  root_tagged.pg_id )
LEFT JOIN root_granted ON ( root_granted.pg_id =  root_tagged.pg_id )

WHERE root_pages.parent_id = '5'
AND root_granted.mem_id = '3'

GROUP BY root_tags.tag_id

UNION ALL

SELECT root_tags.tag_id, root_tags.tag_name, COUNT( root_tagged.pg_id ) CountTags
FROM root_tags

LEFT JOIN root_tagged ON ( root_tagged.tag_id = root_tags.tag_id )
LEFT JOIN root_pages ON ( root_pages.pg_id =  root_tagged.pg_id )

WHERE root_pages.parent_id = '5'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM root_granted
    WHERE root_granted.pg_id =  root_pages.pg_id )

GROUP BY root_tags.tag_id
) SQ
GROUP BY tag_id, tag_name
ORDER BY CountTags DESC
```

Since your WHERE clauses filter against root_granted and root_pages, those are actually INNER JOINs.  You can also use a EXISTS test to emulate the first part of the UNION, **assuming** you can never have more than 1 root_granted record per root_pages record.

```
SELECT root_tags.tag_id, root_tags.tag_name, COUNT( root_tagged.pg_id ) CountTags
FROM root_tags
INNER JOIN root_tagged ON ( root_tagged.tag_id = root_tags.tag_id )
INNER JOIN root_pages ON ( root_pages.pg_id =  root_tagged.pg_id )
WHERE root_pages.parent_id = '5'
AND (NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM root_granted
    WHERE root_granted.pg_id =  root_pages.pg_id )
OR EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM root_granted
    WHERE root_granted.pg_id =  root_pages.pg_id AND root_granted.mem_id = '3'))
GROUP BY root_tags.tag_id, root_tags.tag_name
ORDER BY CountTags DESC
```

Since the `not exists` and `exists` are mutually exclusive, you can combine them using OR for a single query.

Comment: thank you so much for this! why can't I write this beautiful code like you!! sign... thanks! :-)

Comment: the UNION ALL solution seems to have a error as tag_id 16 returns 2 while the INNER JOINs returns 3 which is correct...

Comment: @lau Fixed the UNION ALL solution, it should have been a SUM(Count) not COUNT(COUNT)!

Comment: thank you! it now returns 3! need sometime to digest and study your code! thanks so much!